# plugin thats monitors ontap av connector in icinga2

Tags: windows, nagios, alerts, icinga2, ontap

can you suggest a good plugin for icinga 2 that can monitor and send alerts if ontap av connector is down? Thank you!

We need a plugin that will send alerts or automatically create a ticket if the host or services is down.